# When attempting to retrieve Google Contacts via PeopleV1 API in Ruby Rails, why do I get "ArgumentError: unknown keyword: person_fields"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1, google-people-api

I'm having a hard time integrating Google Contacts into my Ruby (version 2.2.10) on Rails 5 (version 5.1.5) App.

When I execute the following code block, I receive "ArgumentError: unknown keyword: person_fields".

```
people  = Google::Apis::PeopleV1::PeopleService.new
people.authorization = auth_client
response = people.list_person_connections('people/me', page_size: 10, 
person_fields: 'names,emailAddresses')
```

To rectify the problem, I tried using the following gem versions:

gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.11'

gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.8'

gem 'google-api-client'

I still receive the error no matter which version of the gem I use.

Below is the code in its entirety:

```
require 'google/apis/people_v1'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'

client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load 'client_secret_1088824912015-f8asojku302s0mvcijgj7takse8pg8rg.apps.googleusercontent.com.json' 

auth_client = client_secrets.to_authorization

auth_client.update!( :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly', :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback', :additional_parameters => { "access_type" => "offline", "include_granted_scopes" => "true" } )

auth_uri = auth_client.authorization_uri.to_s


# To exchange an authorization code for an access token, use the fetch_access_token! method:

auth_client.code = #auth_code#
auth_client.fetch_access_token!

people  = Google::Apis::PeopleV1::PeopleService.new

people.authorization = auth_client

response = people.list_person_connections('people/me', page_size: 10, person_fields: 'names,emailAddresses')
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct attribute is `fields` not `person_fields`. See docs [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google-api-client/0.9.19/Google/Apis/PeopleV1/PeopleService).

Comment: I've tried `response = people.list_person_connections('people/me', page_size: 10, fields: "names")` to only receive  "Sending HTTP get https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?fields=names&pageSize=10
400 ...>
Caught error badRequest: Request contains an invalid argument.
Error - #<Google::Apis::ClientError: badRequest: Request contains an invalid argument.>

Comment: Then I tried `response = people.list_person_connections('people/me', page_size: 10, request_mask_include_field: "personFields", fields: "names")` to receive "Sending HTTP get https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?fields=names&pageSize=10&requestMask.includeField=personFields
400
...
Caught error badRequest: Request contains an invalid argument.
Error - #<Google::Apis::ClientError: badRequest: Request contains an invalid argument.>

Google::Apis::ClientError: badRequest: Request contains an invalid argument.
 from (irb):27

Comment: Whoops.  Just actually read the doc:
response = people.list_person_connections('people/me', page_size: 10, request_mask_include_field: "person.names")
works. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify for any future readers, Ray Baxte linked to docs corresponding to version `0.9.19` of the `google-api-client` gem - the current version is `0.27.1`

I'm using `0.26.0` and the correct argument is `person_fields` - this obviously changed somewhere between `0.9.19` and `0.26.0`

I follow the documentation in the generated API method definitions:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/0.27.1/generated/google/apis/people_v1/service.rb#L591